# Inside alpine dockers: Permission denied when trying to chmod of a file

Tags: permissions, docker, alpine-linux

I have an alpine docker running, and files are copied into `/root/.ssh/`

Now when I open a shell in this docker and I change the permissions of said file:

```
chmod 400 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I get an permission denied error.

However when I do `ls -l /root/.ssh/id_rsa` I get:

```
-rw-rw-r--    1 root     root          1679 Aug 29 20:57 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Which seems to make sure it is owned by "root". Further testing through running through `id` shwos:

```
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),1(bin),2(daemon),3(sys),4(adm),6(disk),10(wheel),11(floppy),20(dialout),26(tape),27(video)
```

So it seems I *am* running the shell as root, yet I do not have permission to (change) the file permissions of a file that is owned by me? How can this happen?

Comment: How was the file copied to /root/.ssh? Was the file created in the container and just `cp`ed, or was the file copied with `docker cp`, or added via docker volume mounts?
Are you using docker directly on a Linux host, or are you running something like Docker of Mac / Docker for Windows?
Especially the combination of non-linux host and docker volume mounts historically had some weird behaviour...

Can you provide exact steps to reproduce, including at least the `docker run` command and the process to copy/create/add the file?

Comment: @rosaroteelfe it was copied by the COPY instruction inside a dockerfile. Ran in a synology OS (linux based).

Comment: Can you past how you run the docker container?